# User-specific access to folders in Wordpress site

Tags: html, user-access

I want to use selfhosted Wordpress site to show GIS maps to my clients.

I create web maps with gqis2web plugin of QGIS program. It creates folder containing index.html and subfolders with js, css, png and other files. To publish the map, you just need to upload this folder to public section of your site.

According to my idea, a user logins to his private page and gets links to his private maps. But when I upload qgis2web folder to my site, everybody with the link can access this folder without authentication. And I can't give access to this folder to specific user, because this folder is not a wordpress page.

I can imagine two approaches of making qgis2web maps private: 1 - making qgis2web folder inaccessible by direct link and accessible from specific page. Does anybody know if it is possible?

2 - converting qgis2web folder (or at least index.html) to wordpress page. It is more than just copying content of index.html to blank page because you must replace all relative links with absolute links or copy content of all js and css. So does anybody know plugin (or third software) that can do it automatically?